# taxonomy, hierarchical vertices, how do i fetch top parent and selective children?

Tags: python, hierarchy, graph-databases, taxonomy, arangodb

I really enjoyed the graph traversals of arangodb which allows me to visit any path or nodes with little query sweats. However, i m stacked with a context which is already implemented in neo4j, I believe anyone using arangodb might find this useful for his future operation.

I have successfully imported the list of product categories [google product taxonomy](https://www.google.com/basepages/producttype/taxonomy.en-US.txt) into arangodb database. in a vertex collection named `taxonomy` and edge collection named `catof`.

If i m correct, from this query, i m able to fetch all vertices and linked edges.

```
FOR t IN taxonomy
    for c in inbound t catof
    sort c.name asc
    return {c}
```

While feeding the taxonomy documents, parent vertex do not have an edge if any of both parts `_from`, `_to` are null. i need to mention, i m using flask-script and [python-arango](http://python-driver-for-arangodb.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) to proceed on these operations, they have been helpful.

```
manager = Manager(app)
tax_item = storegraph.vertex_collection('taxonomy')
catof = storegraph.edge_collection('catof')

@manager.command
def fetch_tree():

    dictionary = {}

    with open('input.csv') as file:

        for row in file.readlines():

            things = row.strip().split(' > ')
            dictionary[things[0]] = None

            i, j = 0, 1

            while j < len(things):
                parent, child = things[i], things[j]
                dictionary[child] = parent

                i += 1
                j += 1


    # for key in dictionary:
    #tax_item.insert({"name": key})


    for child, parent in dictionary.iteritems():
        # edge_collection.insert_edge({from: vertex_collection / 
        # parent, to: vertex_collection / child})

        chl, par = tax_item.find({'name': child}), 
        tax_item.find({'name': parent})
        c, p = [h for h in chl], [a for a in par]

        if c and p:
        #print 'Child: %s parent: %s' % (c[0]['_id'], p[0]['_id'])
            catof.insert({'_from': c[0]['_id'], '_to': p[0]['_id'] })
            #print '\n'
```

After operation, i have the following sample vertices.

```
[{"_key": "5246198", "_id": "taxonomy/5246198","name": "Computers"},
  {"_key": "5252911", "_id": "taxonomy/5252911","name": "Hardwares"},
  {"_key": "5257587", "_id": "taxonomy/5257587", "name": "Hard disk"
  }]
```

and edges

```
[
{ "_key": "5269883", "_id": "catof/5269883", "_from": "taxonomy/5246198", "_to": "taxonomy/5252911"},
{"_key": "5279833", "_id": "catof/5279833", "_from": "taxonomy/5252911",
"_to": "taxonomy/5257587"}]
```

**Now my question is:** 
How do I fetch only parent documents? i.e `Computers`
From parent documents, how do i print all their children using ? to be a format of `Computers`, `Hardwares`, `Hard Disks`

Comment: Do you want the childrens only of a parent document ?? Or do you want the parent document of any children provided. Please elaborate your question a little further

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want a traversal block, given a vertice id, i would like to fetch it's parents and children if possible. 

I also want to display the tree linking to another collection if only there is a relation between them. 

here is a taxonomy collection, i would like to link to product collection as well, where i have established it's edge named `catof` is of they matched, i want to traverse their node. 

I needed this to build a navigation menu

Comment: Could you please show, for example, in pseudo code, what your expected input and output will be? I am still having a hard to understanding your use case.